Erro 404 in nginx
I created an EC2 instance on AWS and configured Nginx to manage access. I set up a fallback to redirect to Google in case the main server is unavailable.
However, when accessing the configured route, I receive a 404 Not Found error. I need help identifying the issue in my configuration.
Here is the content of the agenciamktmais.shot file located in /etc/nginx/sites-available:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name agenciamktmais.shop;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://bwapp.replit.app;
        proxy_set_header Host bwapp.replit.app;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_ssl_verify off; # Temporário
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header Host www.google.com;
    }

    error_page 502 = @fallback;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name agenciamktmais.shop;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/agenciamktmais.shop/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/agenciamktmais.shop/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://bwapp.replit.app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 30s;

        error_page 502 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}


